# The scraped data saved in csv file is not converted into excel(xlsx) file

Tags: python, excel, csv, scrapy

Here is the code for web scraping and converting saved scraped data from csv 
 formatted to ".xlsx" file.

When I run this code using command line- `scrapy crawl spider_name -o file_name.csv` by extracting from scraping the data into csv 
 format, there will be no excel file generated in project folder. There is no error message. Please suggest what to do to get out of this unknown trouble.

```
import os
import scrapy
import csv
import glob
from openpyxl import Workbook

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        h1_tag = response.xpath('//h1/a/text()').extract_first()
        tags = response.xpath('//*[@class="tag-item"]/a/text()').extract()

        yield {'H1 Tag': h1_tag, 'Tags': tags}

    def close(self, reason):
        csv_file = max(glob.iglob("*.csv"), key=os.path.getctime)

        wb = Workbook()
        ws = wb.active

        with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
            for row in csv.reader(f):
                ws.append(row)

        wb.save(csv_file.replace('.csv', '') + '.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this command:

```
 scrapy crawl <spider name> -o file.csv -t csv
```

Comment: No effect of this command, same thing is happening . Only csv file is generated and not converted excel file is generate. Please suggest some other way to tackle this problem.

Comment: The problem is solved. There is a indentation error which don't display on command prompt, thanks for your sincere effort.